# JavaScript slide show with a different location for the next button for each slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to take a set of screenshots and make them into a walk through tutorial.

The end product I am aiming for is a slide show where on each screen shot the image makes it clear where on the screen shot to advance to the next shot.  When the user clicks that area the show will advance.

I found this jsfiddle from another post on slide shows:

http://jsfiddle.net/rCd26/2/

```js
var interval = undefined;
$(document).ready(function () {
    interval = setInterval(getNext, 2000); // milliseconds
    $('#next').on('click', getNext);
    $('#prev').on('click', getPrev);
});

function getNext() {
    var $curr = $('.slideshow img:visible'),
        $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $('.slideshow img').first();

    transition($curr, $next);
}

function getPrev() {
    var $curr = $('.slideshow img:visible'),
        $next = ($curr.prev().length) ? $curr.prev() : $('.slideshow img').last();
    transition($curr, $next);
}

function transition($curr, $next) {
    clearInterval(interval);

    $next.css('z-index', 2).fadeIn('slow', function () {
        $curr.hide().css('z-index', 0);
        $next.css('z-index', 1);
    });

}
```

```css
.slideshow {
    position: relative;
    /* necessary to absolutely position the images inside */
    width: 500px;
    /* same as the images inside */
    height: 100px;
}
.slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.slideshow img:first-child {
    display: block;
    /* overrides the previous style */
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100/0000CD&text=1" width="500" height="100" alt="first image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100/008000&text=2" width="500" height="100" alt="second image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100/B22222&text=3" width="500" height="100" alt="third image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100/F4A460&text=4" width="500" height="100" alt="fourth image">
</div>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

I think there are 3 things I need to do to make it work for me:

1. Be able to position the next button within the image.
2. Be able to change the size of the next button (creating different size hotspots).
3. Be able to change the location of the hotspot by image.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: That example uses jQuery 1.9.1, try adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` to your `<head></head>` section and refresh the page (it should be the first Javascript loaded to avoid any conflicts later). Everything else could be achieved using just CSS and a couple of HTML containers (`div`s)

Comment: Thanks Ivan. sorry not very familiar with JS.  How would you make it generate a new css tag for each next button so I could reposition it?

Comment: You usually ser a container with a defined `width` and `height` and with `position: relative;` (that's the parent `div`) and then the child elements (like your buttons) can be positioned absolutelly (`position: absolute;`) inside that parent div (using `top: 10px;` and `left: 20px;` for example, you could also use `right: 25px;` to position from the right of the container). Let me write an answer, give me a moment.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `.slideview` element which is relatively positioned in the document, so images can be absolutely positioned inside of it. We'll be using the same technique for positioning your buttons. Let's create a new "global" container:

```
<div class="global_container">
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100/0000CD&text=1" width="500" height="100" alt="first image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100/008000&text=2" width="500" height="100" alt="second image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100/B22222&text=3" width="500" height="100" alt="third image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100/F4A460&text=4" width="500" height="100" alt="fourth image">
    </div>
    <button id="prev">Prev</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Now in your CSS add this class:

```
.global_container { /* selector for a class called global_container */
    position: relative;
    width: 500px; /* same width as your slider, probably use a couple pixels more */
    height: 100px; /* whatever height you want, usually more than your slider height or equal */
}
```

Now, as your global container has `position: relative;`, you can position elements inside (adding a `position: absolute;` to their CSSes). So add to your CSS:

```
#prev { /* selector for the element with id="prev" */
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px; /* button will be positioned 45px from the top of the global container */
    left: 10px; /* and 10px from the left of the global container */
}

#next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px; /* same as before */
    right: 10px; /* same as before, but from the right of the global container */

    /* you could even set the size of the buttons */
    width: 40px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So I need to be able to have #next1 #next2 so I can move the next button on each slide.  I am trying to edit the javascript to get it to work such that the next button can change location based on slide.  Does that make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by "mode the next button on each slide"? That every slide has its own button that moves with it? I'm not sure how to do that.